# Syntax changes between Python 3 and Python 2 when writing to a log file

Tags: python, logging

My job currently utilizes python 2.7 for scripting. However, I'm currently working on script with python 3.7. Normally, when we need to write to a log file the code looks like this:

`log = file(r'\\server\blah\result.log', 'w')`

`print >>log, 'BEGIN DAILY REPORT ' + strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", localtime()) + '\n`

However, in 3.7 I'm getting this error : "NameError: name 'file' is not defined". Is this the result of syntax changes? Forgive me as I'm new to python.

Comment: It should be `log = open(r'\\server\blah\result.log', 'w')`

Comment: `file` was never the recommended way to open a file, even in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file in Python 3.x, you need to use `open(filename, mode)`.

[Look here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more information and examples.